# Android : How to prevent any View from being hidden by Soft Keyboard?

Tags: android, view, hidden, soft-keyboard

I have 4 lines of input fields in my Layout.
The problem is that when i click the uppermost `EditText`, soft keyboard appears and hides the lowermost `EditText`.
**My Goal is to keep every EditText fields visible in screen when soft keyboard pops up.**

I tried `windowSoftInputMode` in Manifest but that's not what I wanted, it just keeps the 'focused' input field visible.

Is there any flags for `View` type to prevent hiding from soft keyboard, so that the screen always scrolls to show the specified Views?

Answer (score 1):

You can put 4 lines of input fields into a linearlayout view then put this linearlayout into a scrollview, when soft keyboard appears, you scroll the scrollview to  the last EditText view position.

```
int[] loc = new int[2];

lastEditTextView.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
```

the method to detect keyboard appears:

```
private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener mOnGlobalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        if (activityRootView == null) {
            return;
        }
        activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);

        if (heightDiff > 100) {
            // keyboard show
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(loc[0],loc[1]);
        } else {
            // keyboard hidden
        }
    }
};

activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(mOnGlobalLayoutListener);
```

Comment: Thanks, I could solve the issue using the fundamental idea from this answer!